# QT project and USB connection

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have problems with FTD2xx driver.
I'm using QT(C++) in Fedora 26 (64-bit) and the last version of FTD2xx for "2232H" device.
Also the build method is:

```
qmake /Address/ProjectName.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

Problem:

The FT_Status return 0(FT_OK) at ft_openex(....) command, but that return none_zero(FT_OK) for other functions of FTD2xx lib;
A section of my code:

```
FT_HANDLE   ftH;
FT_STATUS   ftStatus;
ftStatus = FT_OpenEx(const_cast<char*>("MYDevName"), FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &ftH);
std::cout<<"FTST open:"<< ftStatus<<std::endl;
char a[10];DWORD b;
ftStatus = FT_SetBitMode(&ftH,0xff,0);
std::cout<<"FTST RESET:"<< ftStatus<<std::endl;
ftStatus = FT_SetBitMode(&ftH,0xff,0x40);
std::cout<<"FTST SPEED:"<< ftStatus<<std::endl;
ftStatus = FT_Close(&ftH);
std::cout<<"FTST CLOSE:"<< ftStatus<<std::endl;

And output :
FTST open:0
FTST RESET:1
FTST SPEED:1
FTST CLOSE:1
```

```
ftStatus =1 ;means FT_INVALID_HANDLE.
and
Command <<rmmod ftdi_sio >> is using.
and
Lib directory: /dev/local/lib
and
QT setting:
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lftd2xx
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also I don't think this has anything to do with Qt. Even though your project uses `qmake` and Qt you don't get linking or runtime issues so errors like what you describe come from the logic you are using when working with the API of the FTD2xx and/or some other issue that comes from the API/board itself.

Comment: I have same code with different driver (libftdi) in a same hardware. but because of some problems as chunk_size and ... , i'm testing the second driver (libftd2xx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FT_HANDLE` is an output parameter in `FT_OpenEx`.  You are correctly passing `&ftH` so that the function can overwrite `ftH`.

The `FT_HANDLE` is an input parameter to the other functions.  You are incorrectly passing `&ftH` and should pass just `ftH`.

<strike>`FT_Close(&ftH);`</strike>
`FT_Close(ftH);`

Unfortunately `FT_HANDLE` is defined in a loosely-typed way:

```
typedef void* PVOID;
typedef PVOID FT_HANDLE;
```

Since `void**` implicitly converts to `void*`, the compiler cannot help you catch this mistake<sup>1</sup>.  In general opaque handle types should be declared as

```
typedef struct AlwaysIncompleteType * MY_HANDLE;
```

and then the pointer and double-pointer types will be appropriately incompatible.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even worse, in C, the reverse conversion from `void*` to `void**` is *also* implicit and you would be allowed to call `FT_OpenEx(..., ftH)` probably resulting in an immediate access violation (aka segmentation fault) and possibly resulting in unpredictable memory corruption.  At least C++ got this right... but `void*` is still not conducive to strong type checking.